# Can I assign a value to a non-const reference parameter?

Tags: c++

In the following (legacy) code block, is the assignment to popped_value valid or should there be a memcpy ?

```
bool peek(value_type& popped_value)
    {
    bool retval=false;
    RWLock::ScopedReadLock lock(queueLock);
    if ( ! m_queue.empty())
        {
        popped_value=m_queue.front(); //question...
        retval=true;
        }
    return retval;
    }
```

I don't want to change the parameter to a pointer.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Assuming `m_queue` has a compatible type, it is correct.

Comment: It depends on what `value_type` is. If it is a well behaved type with value semantics there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It passes the test case but that could just be because the test case is so simple. The fact that I can't think of a way to test it that fails suggests it is OK, but it seems to me that my understanding [of a reference parameter being merely an alias for a variable that is outside the current scope] is flawed. I would have expected the compiler to throw out the reassignment of the reference but it accepts it and I'm puzzled.

Comment: yes, @Jarod42:  std::deque <value_type> m_queue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place you can set the object that a reference variable references is when the reference variable is created:

- In the case of a global or local variable, the `Type & ref = value;` statement that defines the variable,
- In the case of a non-static data member of some class, the initialization list in a constructor for that class, or
- In the case of an argument to some function that is a reference, in the statement that calls that function.

At any other time, you are not changing the thing that reference variable references when you assign a value to that reference, e.g., `reference_variable = value;`. You are instead changing the value of the thing to which that reference variable refers.

That almost certainly is exactly the desired behavior in the referenced block of code.

Comment: Well "At any other time, you are not changing the thing that reference variable references when you assign a value to that reference, e.g., reference_variable = value;. You are instead changing the value of the thing to which that reference variable refers." certainly explains my misunderstanding. So there's a dark secret to references... I was upset when they abused the venerable '&' operator by reusing it for references in C++

Answer (score 1):

That's fine, and it's how I would expect that to be written.

If `value_type` is a custom class, then some `value_type operator=(...)` will be called. Presumably the implementation of this method is sane.